# Upgrading a django 1.4 project to 1.8 version

Tags: django

I am new to django and i have a django 1.4 version project. i am trying to run it in django 1.8 environment. I'd like to upgrade my 1.4 project to 1.8 without rewriting the project.
If someone knows a way to do this please help me. I tried surfing for answers but couldn't find any.

Comment: Check on developer site in upgrade section

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic answer I am afraid.

You'll need to read the Django release notes for [1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.5/), [1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.6/), [1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.7/) and [1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/), and make any appropriate changes to your code.

Django recently [updated their release roadmap](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2015/jun/25/roadmap/), which will make it easier to upgrade from the current LTS 1.8 to the next LTS 1.11.